# Can a contains search be made in ElasticSearch in the search query?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I created a `Django` project to learn `ElasticSearch` and when I search for users in this project, when I enter the username of the user exactly, the result is returned. Can I set this to contains as in Django ORM?

I use "match" because I just know it.

```
q = request.GET.get('q')
users = UserDocument.search().query("match", username=q)
```

Answer (score 0):

match query uses the same analyzer which is used at index time on the field which you are searching on, for example you are searching in your example on `username` and if you have defined `username` to be `text` field without any explicit analyzer, than `match` query will use the default analyzer of `text` field which is [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), which splits the token based on whitespace and remove special chars.

You can text the tokens generated using the [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html), to support the contains use-case, you need to define a analyzer which generates your search term tokens, would be great if you can share some sample documents and your search term so that we can provide some working example.